# SqlConnection.OpenAsync unrecognized

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

This is the exact error I'm getting:

> 'SqlConnection' does not contain a definition for 'OpenAsync' and no extension method 'OpenAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'SqlConnection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```cs
//other usings
using System.Data.SqlClient;
//other code
public async Task<bool> testCnxTimeout(SqlConnection cnx)
{
    cnx.OpenAsync();  //this line produces the error
    return true;
}
```

OpenAsync is a function in the MSDN documentation for SqlConnection [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx). I was able to do other query operations flawlessly in other parts of the code. I thought it might be the fact that I was calling it from a synchronous context, so I put it in an asynchronous task (I'm not new to multithreading, but this is the first time I've used it in C#), but that wasn't it: OpenAsync is just not recognized at all. System.Data.dll is version 4.0.0.0, and the target platform for the application is a 64-bit Windows PC.
Is there something really simple I'm missing here?

Comment: What is the target platform for your Net Framework?

Comment: BTW, when/if you get it working, you need to await that async call or the connection might not be open by the time you attempt to use it.

Comment: Sounds like you're referencing an older version of `System.Data.dll`.  Check the version number on it.

Comment: System.Data is version 4.0.0.0. I installed Visual Studio on my machine about a month ago. The target platform is (I believe) 64-bit Windows.

Comment: I believe by "target platform" @Steve meant "target framework" (check the project's properties). You can't access async methods in .NET versions before 4.5.

Comment: Thanks! That at least answers my question as to why it's not working. That gives me enough to get started on fixing it